# What's the difference between these queries MySQL date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have table called order_match with this column

```
+----+-----------+
| id | createdAt |
+----+-----------+
```

so I want to make query to find out ID which appear in between range 7 days  behind

I have 2 queries, idk which one is true and why it is become true

query 1

```
SELECT om.id
    FROM order_match om
    WHERE om.createdAt >= 
    DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  AND
    om.createdAt <
    ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
    GROUP BY om.id;
```

and it returns 57 id

query 2

```
SELECT om.id
    FROM order_match om
    WHERE om.createdAt >= 
    now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY  AND
    om.createdAt <
    now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY om.id;
```

and it return 2 id

idk which one is true? or both of those queries are false?

```
EXPECTED RESULTS

assume curdate = '2020-02-05'

THEN IF the table was become like this

+----+------------+
| id | createdAt  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2020-02-02 |
|  2 | 2020-02-03 |
|  3 | 2020-02-04 |
+----+------------+

THEN all of the ID are included because the ids was on the range between 2020-02-05  and 7 days behind (2020-01-30 00:00:00)
```

Comment: *ID which appear in between range 7 days behind* - You need to be more specific than that.

Comment: ok let me edit it

Comment: Can you share sample data such that others could reproduce the problem?

Comment: done sir, i've input the expected results

Comment: Neither. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: it's because some id can be duplicate (multiple transaction), so i put the group by because i want to find out how many the users

Comment: If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query finds a 9 day range beginning at midnight of 7 days ago; your second query finds only an *8* day range beginning at the *current time* 7 days ago.  Since the ranges are different, it is not surprising the results are different.

Comment: so based on my expected results, then which one is true?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "true".  Either should return all three records of your sample data.

Comment: yeah but on my real data, there's significant difference count of users.

Comment: Yes, because they two select different lengths of ranges starting at different earliest points.  I tried to explain what the two queries do; only you can decide which is what you meant, if either